# Prevent .on click when class in body is present.\

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really confused by this. I'd like a click to only happen when a class in the body is present, and not when a different class is present.

When you click, I'm adding the class to the body, but in my code, jquery is still allowing the action to happen on click.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/omarel/pen/LLbwyq

HTML

```
<html>
<body class="comp-mode-off">

  <div class="sharelink">click</div>
  <div class="togglecompmode">toggle comp mode</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JQUERY

```
var sharelinkbtn =  $( ".comp-mode-off .sharelink" ); 

$( sharelinkbtn ).on( "click", function() {
     alert("hi"); //should only happen when .comp-mode-off exists. 
 }); 

$( '.togglecompmode' ).on( "click", function() {

   $('body').toggleClass( "comp-mode-off comp-mode-on"); //but when i remove it, it still happens

 });
```

Comment: Binding the event handler to the element happens only once, and the handler stays bound - you can change class names all you want afterwards, it doesn’t matter any more. You need to either use event delegation; or have the handler fire in any case, but inside decide whether to do something or not based on if that element currently has the class or not.

Comment: jquery collections are not live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding on the element which is selected initially but updating body `class` doesn't make any change to the attached handler. So use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to fire only when class exists for the body.

```
// use the selector as second argument
$(document).on( "click", 'body.comp-mode-off .sharelink', function() {
   alert("hi"); 
});
```

```js
$(document).on("click", 'body.comp-mode-off .sharelink', function() {
  alert("hi");
});

$('.togglecompmode').on("click", function() {

  $('body').toggleClass("comp-mode-off comp-mode-on");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="comp-mode-off">

  <div class="sharelink">click</div>
  <div class="togglecompmode">toggle comp mode</div>
</body>
```

---

Or check within the handler that class exists for the body.

```
var sharelinkbtn =  $( ".comp-mode-off .sharelink" ); 

$( sharelinkbtn ).on( "click", function() {
   // check class exists or not 
   if($('body.comp-mode-off').length){
   // or use $('body').hasClass('comp-mode-off')

      alert("hi");
   }
});
```

```js
var sharelinkbtn = $(".comp-mode-off .sharelink");

$(sharelinkbtn).on("click", function() {
  // check class exists or not 
  if ($('body.comp-mode-off').length) {
    // or use $('body').hasClass('comp-mode-off')

    alert("hi");
  }
});

$('.togglecompmode').on("click", function() {

  $('body').toggleClass("comp-mode-off comp-mode-on"); //but when i remove it, it still happens

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="comp-mode-off">

  <div class="sharelink">click</div>
  <div class="togglecompmode">toggle comp mode</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The first snippet doesn't change things. Do I have to use a conditional statement for this?

Comment: @Omar : what you mean ?

Comment: your first code snippet doesn't have an affect on anything. The link is still clickable despite the class change. So I'm wondering is the only way to use a IF ELSE conditional statement.

Comment: oh it does work. It doesn't work when stored in a var like this: var sharelinkbtn =  $( "body.comp-mode-off .sharelink" );
$( document ).on( "click", sharelinkbtn, function() {...

Comment: @Omar : glad to help you :)